# Manuscript was "unsubmitted" because the manuscript was deposited in Arxiv Preprints

Tags: paper-submission, preprint, biology

One of my manuscripts was "unsubmitted" and potentially rejected by the journal for the reason that it was submitted to a preprint server. Is it normal for the journal to reject a paper that was submitted in a preprint?

Comment: @TommiBrander Biological science published under De Gruyter. Most of my papers in the field were all submitted to preprint servers before I submit it to formal submission to a journal. This journal is quite weird to unsubmit my MS. Any suggestion how to appeal?

Comment: Don't appeal. That just wastes your time. Just find a more reasonable journal.

Comment: "Normal" depends on the field. Please include that in the question (not just the tags) and, assuming that biology varies in its practices as much as computer science does, you'll probably need to be more specific than that.

Comment: @MaartenBuis "Appealing is a waste of time" is reasonable advice if the paper was 'unsubmitted' by an editor. However, if it was done automatically right after submission by the journal editorial staff (I mean, not the academics, the employees), then it would be a good idea to let the editors know that this happened, in case they aren't informed yet.

Comment: How do you know your manuscript was unsubmitted? Did they send you an email saying your manuscript has been unsubmitted because it's been submitted to a preprint server?

Comment: "unsubmitted" is not the same as "rejected because previously published on Arxiv". Please quote exactly what the journal has said.

Comment: Another potential concern is for journals with double-blind reviewing policies. The argument could be made that posting to arXiv violates this since a reviewer could potentially see the paper and your identity would be revealed.

Comment: @Allure the journal contacted me informing the decision and the reason why they "unsubmitted" my MS. Although I appealed already pointing that it is not included in their policy and the journal is under SHERPA/RoMEO that allows preprints.

Answer (score 38):

Most journals now allow and even encourage the use of preprint servers. Some, however, still prohibit it on the notion that it is competition with their own publication of the article, or even consider it self-plagiarism. This tends to be field-dependent as well: some fields (e.g., physics, mathematics) are very liberal in policy, while others tend to be more retrogressive (e.g., chemistry, certain portions of biology).

The only way to tell a particular journal's policy, however, is to check the specific journal ([the SHERPA/RoMEO database](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php) is also highly helpful, since it's easier to find the policies there and they have been pre-interpreted by experts).

If you have, indeed, been prohibited from submission due to a journal's policy on preprints, my only advice is to find another that allows it.

Comment: I checked the Journal in SHERPA/RoMEO database and it's under RoMeo Yellow publishers. It says "author can archive pre-print (ie pre-refereeing)" so pre-prints are allowed? correct me if Im wrong about my interpretation

Comment: Apparently the database is wrong in this case. Mistakes happen, it is a large database after all, and it  summarizes complex policies into 4 color codes. So consider that database a starting point when searching for journals, but don't rely on it.

Comment: @xavier that would be the interpretation, yes - preprints allowed.

Comment: @Allure thanks! I appealed to the journal using this database. I hope they will reconsider.

Comment: @xavier Did you check if the journal had any preprint policy (or "policy on prior publication" or similar) on their website? Clearly that would override any listing in a third-party database.

Comment: @Anyon No mention of pre-prints or any third party database.

Comment: @Anyon Although the journal only says that "Multiple, redundant or concurrent publication in one journal or major publication". In this case, I believe Preprints are not considered a major publication.

Comment: @xavier By third-party database I meant the SHERPA/RoMEO one, which the journal would be unlikely to mention in its policies. Anyway, I guess you could sit back and wait for their reply for now.

Comment: @jakebeal Chemistry is getting better. Two of the largest chemistry publishers (ACS and the Royal Society of Chemistry) started the Chemrxiv preprint server and Elvesier and Wiley both say that accept papers that have previously been put online as preprints.

Comment: @Tyberius That's good to know --- this is the first time I've heard of ChemRxiv.  bioRxiv has certainly helped to open up the bio community quickly, and hopefully ChemRxiv will do the same for chemistry.